# using methods inside classes as callback

Tags: php, class, object, methods

i am building a class and it contains some methods

in some method i tried to use `[array_map][1]` function and make it's `$callback` a method which is defined inside the same class so i tried

`array_map('$this->something()',$this->somearray);`

but it didn't work ! and caused this error

`function '$this->something' not found or invalid`

any ideas to use an internal method in the class as a callback ?

Comment: If you're using PHP >= 5.3 then just use a closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PHP >= 5.3 then just use a closure.

```
array_map(function($a) {}, $this->somearray);
```

Otherwise it should be:

```
array_map(array($this, 'something'), $this->somearray);
```